# Does SQL Server faithfully handle circular WKT representations like CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE and CURVEPOLYGON?

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, postgis, r-sf, geos

Having had a look around at the spatial data ecosystem it looks like the major open source libraries which handle GEOMETRY operations like intersection and area all seem to linearise circular curves when it comes to implementing INTERSECTION or AREA or they don't handle CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE and CURVEPOLYGON data types at all (a lot of this seems to be that libgeos/GEOS doesn't currently handle that data type and many libraries link to GEOS to handle these operations)

So this includes postgis, sf (R package), spatialite, libgeos itself. However SQL Server does seem to faithfully handle circular arcs for intersection (confirmed by eye simply by looking at a lot of intersections - SQL Server is closed source from what I can tell so I can't know for sure) but I don't know whether the AREA algorithm is linearised or not.

0. Can anyone correct me if my view of the situation above is incorrect
1. Does anyone know whether SQL Server faithfully handles the area of circular GEOMETRY types?
2. Does anyone know of an open source library that also handles circular types faithfully?

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL server"? If the Microsoft thing you might want to state it more clearly.

Comment: Yup the Microsoft relational DBMS, it has native geospatial capabilities that seem divorced from the rest of the GEOS/GDAL/PROJ ecosystem. As for stating it more clearly what is its name other than SQL Server?

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure. But it seems to me that if this is important to you, you'd have some way to test that is more robust than "confirmed by eye simply by looking at a lot of intersections". That is, come up with a suite of tests that validate (or invalidate) *any* spatial implementation for your purposes.